# Why do UIView & UIImageView animate differently?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have 4 buttons, all use the same animate func

- imageViewWithoutDelay
- imageViewWithDelay
- ViewWithoutDelay
- ViewWithDelay

my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func imageViewithoutDelay(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let circleImage = UIImageView()
        // kindly add your own image.
        circleImage.image = UIImage(named: "empty")
        animate(inputView: circleImage, delay: false)
    }

    @IBAction func imageViewWithDelay(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let circleImage = UIImageView()
        circleImage.image = UIImage(named: "empty")
        animate(inputView: circleImage, delay: true)
    }

    func animate(inputView : UIView, delay: Bool){

        inputView.layer.cornerRadius = inputView.frame.size.width / 2
        inputView.clipsToBounds = true
        inputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(inputView)

        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height * 0.10
        inputView.center.y = screenHeight
        view.setNeedsLayout()
        view.setNeedsDisplay()

        if delay == true{
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, animations: {
                inputView.alpha = 0.0
                let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
                let screenHeight = screenSize.height * 0.10
                inputView.center.y -= screenHeight
            })
        })} else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, animations: {
                inputView.alpha = 0.0
                let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
                let screenHeight = screenSize.height * 0.10
                inputView.center.y -= screenHeight
            })

        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

What amuses me is the different behavior of the `UIview` & `UIImageView`.

The `UIImageView` instance only animates as intended (going up *from origin*) *if* I use delay. However, without using a delay block, UIImageView instance first drops down, then animates going up *to its origin*).

The `UIView` doesn’t show different behaviors. It animates from its origin and goes up.

[image]
Is this a bug?

This question is a tangent to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121814/uiview-animation-is-doing-my-animation-reversed#comment71501832_42121814) original question.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is wrong no matter how you slice it. You cannot add a view and animate it all in the same breath. You can only animate a view that is *already in* the interface.

That is why it works for the image view if you add the delay: by the time you animate, the image view has gotten into the interface and the interface has settled down.

The fact that it seems to work for the non-imageview is just dumb luck.

Comment: I see. 1. by the time it gets to the animation line, isn't it already in the interface? 2. why does it happen this way? I mean why does it shift? Shouldn't there be a reason of why it can't happen and why it can for imageView.

Comment: I don't know why it works for the non-imageview. — It isn't "in the interface" until the runloop has a chance to cycle. Even a delay of zero should be enough, because you'll come back in on the main thread on the next runloop. Try it on your image view and see.

Comment: You mean change to `.seconds(0)`? I did that, and now both my imageViews drop down then animate up to origin. I also tried `.nanoseconds(1)` and still got same incorrect result.

Comment: Maybe it gets optimized away. I was thinking use `DispatchQueue.async {...}` instead of your `asyncAfter`. Or use my [`delay` utility](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994) and try `delay(0)` — but if that doesn't work, try something like `delay(.01)`. Let's see what you find out...